# Comparing an epoch with current date in epoch format

Tags: postgresql

How can I compare a column value with current date's epoch format ?

Tried following query :

```
select f_id from (select (extract(epoch from now()))) as epochNow, data_history 
where   (extract(epoch from f_lastmodified) + f_retention_period) < epochNow 

ERROR :
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: operator does not exist: double precision < record
SQL state: 42883
```

Any pointers ?

Comment: Why do you need an epoch format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select f_id 
from data_history 
where   (extract(epoch from f_lastmodified) + f_retention_period) < extract(epoch from now())
```

When you wrote:

```
from (select (extract(epoch from now()))) as epochNow
```

you created a subquery thar returns 1 row with one column. And you named this subquery `epochNow`

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering if there is any way to retrieve UTC time stored in DB ?

Comment: @user1122559 It depends on how you stored it to the db.